# JBoss / Dashbuilder Embed code not working

Tags: javascript, jboss, embed, kpi

I am trying to embed a KPI table in another page. I modified the sample provided in the instructions here (page X) and came up with:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashbuilder Javascript API</title>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder/js-api/dashbuilder-1.0.0.js"></script>
<style>
.code {
padding:10px;
background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-radius: 3px;
border-style: solid;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="embedCharts();">
<span class="code">dashbuilder_embed_chart('Hawkwood At-Risk', 'http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder', 'kpi_18141464209498716', 600, 350);</span>
<br/>
<!-- Very simple layout with charts -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" >
<tr>
<td id="chart1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End of charts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function embedCharts() {
var dashbuilderUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder';
dashbuilder_embed_chart('Hawkwood At-Risk', dashbuilderUrl, 'kpi_18141464209498716', 600, 350);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But all I come up with on the resulting page is a box with the text " dashbuilder_embed_chart('Hawkwood At-Risk', 'http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder', 'kpi_18141464209498716', 600, 350);" inside.

I was able to verify the presence of the file http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder/js-api/dashbuilder-1.0.0.js.

Can you see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  The proper embed code was:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashbuilder Javascript API</title>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder/js-api/dashbuilder-1.0.0.js"></script>
<style>
.code {
padding:10px;
background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-radius: 3px;
border-style: solid;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="embedCharts();">
<!-- Very simple layout with charts -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" >
<tr>
<td id="chart1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End of charts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function embedCharts() {
var dashbuilderUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/dashbuilder';
dashbuilder_embed_chart('chart1', dashbuilderUrl, 'kpi_18141464209498716', 600, 350);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```